Changing local user folder in Windows 11 Home
I got a new laptop, logged in in my Microsoft account. Windows created a folder for me as a new user, but that forlder is named weirdly. I never entered that sequence of charcters anywhere. It's an abridged version of my email, I reckon. It doesn't match anything. Imagine you had an email jack.smith@gmail.com, then the folder would be named users/jacksm
Now, before too many apps start to rely on that faulty user path, I want to fix it. Simply renaming the folder doesn't seem to be a good idea. So I executed netplwiz and changed the user name. Problem is the folder keeps the same name, so I'm back to square one: is it ok to simply rename the folder?
I have Windows 11 Home, not Windows 11 Pro, so lusrmgr.msc is not an option
So how do I handle it gracefully?

It used to be easy. You just disconnect the MSA from the account, you would get a prompt to rename your profile, log back into your account and link the MSA back to the account. I have numerous answers to that effect. Today I am tired looks like your stuck doing this. The method you used so far, has never and cannot be used to rename your user profile directory.

As @Ramhound states, it is not simple, and prone to user error in the process, possibly requiring Windows be reinstalled. However, with a local account, the folder is simply the user name.
